# how do I remove trailing dot on my domain with redirecting

Tags: .htaccess, web, url, redirect

I have to make sure that all my websites are redirected to 
https://www.domain.co.uk/ + the request e.g contact or faq

Currently my htaccess works for redirecting these domains
https://domain.co.uk
http://domain.co.uk
http://www.domain.co.uk

However I need it to also redirect domains like these
https://domain.co.uk.
https://domain.co.uk./contact
http://www.domain.co.uk./contact
and many other combinations that break my website.

I also need to make sure that if its on localhost then it wont redirect e.g.
localhost/contact

As  I have mentioned above i need it for all my websites so it musn't be a specific domain.
e.g. should work with [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) and [www.domain.co.uk](http://www.domain.co.uk).

I'm having problems with fixing the trailing dot redirect

Heres my code i have right now.

```
php_flag log_errors on
php_value error_reporting 32767
php_value error_log "error_log.txt"

RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !localhost [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !localhost [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

Header always set Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
```

Edit1: I have tried other solutions but they don't seem to work or doesn't do completely what I want

Edit2: I'm very new to htaccess syntax so I don't completely understand it. I have tried the following code and they dont do what i want or anything at all. These are the ones i have saved.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.+)\.$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} //|..
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0 [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: So what have you actually tried?

Comment: "domain.co.uk." is not a valid host name. So the question is why you need to handle that at all... Where do such requests come from? Wouldn't it make more sense to fix that actual cause instead of trying to handle the symptom?

Comment: @arkascha could you clarify what you mean by domain.co.uk not being a valid host name? I am getting 2 errors a day on my website with mysql, and I have recreated that error by trying to access my website with a trailing dot at the end.

Comment: "domain.co.uk" most likely is a valid host name. But "domain.co.uk." is something different, it has a trailing dot. That is a host name that cannot be resolved. So the only way I can imagine that http requests target your http server is if they origin from a client that has setup that name in the local name resolution, so most likely one of _your_ development systems...

Comment: On the contrary, @arkascha, the domain name with a trailing dot is a perfectly valid, fully qualified/absoluta/complete DNS name. Actually, without the trailing dot, it is a relative domain name that should be completed using another domain name that comes from the context where the name is used. In practice, the context is most often the root domain, which has an empty label -- the root domain's label in fact comes after the trailing dot. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1034#section-3.1

Comment: On fully qualified domain names... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name